# django - How to access the different classes with its User?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

This is my models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Images')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.caption, self.user.username)


class ProfilePic(Image):
    pass



class BackgroundPic(Image):
    pass


class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Photo(Image):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=3)
```

And this is another:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    permanent_address = models.TextField()
    temporary_address = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePic)
    background_pic = models.ForeignKey(BackgroundPic)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I can access the Parent class with its User object.

```
>>>m = User.objects.get(username='mika')
>>>m.image_set.all()
>>>[<Image: mika_photo - mika>, <Image: mika_pro - mika>, <Image: mika_bf - mika>]
```

But I can't access its child class with the User. I tried:

```
>>>m.Image.profilepic_set.all()
```

and

```
>>>m.image_set.profilpic.all()
```

and this

**Edit**

```
>>>m.profilepic_set.all() 
AttributeError:'User' object has no attribute 'profilepic_set'
```

But all gave me errors!

**Edit**

How do I access the child classes, so that I can add images from one class to another.

Eg: Copy image from Photo to ProfilePic, or from ProfilePic to BackgroundPic and so. Or simply, how to add images for particular User in specific classes?

**Edit**

What I want is that, each user will have a set of `profile pictures`, `background images` and other set of `photos uploaded`. These images will be kept separately in the templates. And if the user wants, he can easily use (copy) the other set of photos uploaded or images from the background image set, as the profile picture, and that image will be added to `profile picture set`. Or if he wants, he can use an image from `profile picture set` or from the other `uploaded photos` as the `background image` and similarly that image used from other class will be copied to `background image set`.

Please guide me to achieve the above mentioned. Will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what errors do they give you ? Also, is your class model definition really `pass` ?

Comment: @karthikr Please see the edit. And yes, all of them has pass. I am newbie here, please correct me if I am wrong. And how do I achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: It's usual to have a situation in which it's good design to have models use multiple table inheritance from a non-abstract parent but have no special behavior themselves. What are you trying to do with this design?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Suppose, I uploaded an Image. Then I should be able to use it as profile_pic/background_pic in the UserProfile of the user, so that I can use it as profile_pic/background image in the template. And also, if had to, I could easily use the `background_pic` and use it for `profile_pic` by appending or adding it the image that I want from `backgroudn_pic` to the `profile_pic`, and also opposite. I hope I was clear. Please ask me, it wasn't.

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to me. For that, I don't see why you need more than an `Image` model, and then the foreign keys on the `UserProfile` model.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `Image` model is to get the latest image uploaded by the user. :)
And other classes are to separate them from each other. Please correct me if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, watch out for User model that has changed since Django 1.5 : you can now provide a User model without linking to Django "user" class.

Then, there are 2 things you can do :

(as Peter explained)

```
ProfilePic.objects.filter(user=m)
```

When you do not want to link the pic to the user (but rather link the user to the pic)

```
class User (models.Model):
    pic = models.ForeignKey(Pic)

class Pic (models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

u = User.objects.get(pk=42)
u.pic # --> gives you the one picture that a user can have

p = Pic.objects.get(pk=42)
p.user_set # --> gives you 0 to (many) users that have this pic linked to it.
```

if Each User can have many pictures and every pictures can have many users, what you want is "many_to_many_field".

If you want an avatar for the user, use a picture in the "User" object.
If you want to have several pictures for the user (as in "album") use the ForeignKey to a picture model.
If you want to have several pictures linked to several user (as in "mark as favourite"), use many to many.

Then, for copying a file to an other file, use this kind of things :

```
from PIL import Image
class MyImages(models.Model):
      photo_one = models.ImageField(upload_to="one/", blank=True, null=True)
      photo_two = models.ImageField(upload_to="two/", blank=True, null=True)
      def copy(self):
           self.photo_two.save(self.photo_one.name, ContentFile(file(self.photo_one.path).read()))
```

Comment: What I want is that, each user will have a set of `profile pictures`, `background images` and other set of `photos uploaded`. These images will be kept separately in the templates. And if the user wants, he can easily use (copy) the other set of photos uploaded or images from the background image set, as the profile picture, and that image will be added to `profile picture set`. Or if he wants, he can use an image from `profile picture set` or from the other `uploaded photos` as the `background image` and similarly that image used from other class will be copied to `background image set`.

Comment: As I said, many to many in that case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be just to filter directly on your inherited models:

```
ProfilePic.objects.filter(user=m)
```

I can't recall offhand if the related `_set` syntax you're using works with inherited models in any form or not.

You also have foreign keys defined for `profile_pic` and `background_pic` on your `UserProfile` model - if you're trying to access those images, they work as normal for foreign keys:

```
m.profile_pic
```

I am not sure why you have both foreign keys and a specialized subclass that does nothing.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But suppose, if I had to, how do I append or add more images from other class to `ProfilePic` or `BackgroundPic`?

Comment: I am a little confused about what you're trying to do. You can set a user profile's `profile_pic` attribute directly: `m.profile_pic = some_image_instance`.